# Shuffle array of custom objects

Tags: php, arrays, shuffle

I'm new to PHP (coming from ASPNET) and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding why this isn't working. I'd like to shuffle an array (of custom Quote objects) but when I call the shuffle() function it seems to simply return an integer value (presumably a random number).

According to the manual I should be able to call shuffle and pass in my array:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php

```
/**
* @public
* Retrieves a collection of Quote objects from the datasource
* @param string $author An optional author to filter on
* @return array 
*/
public function GetRandom($author='') {
  //ToDo: Work out correct way to randomize array!
  //return shuffle($this->GetAllQuotes($author));

  // This is my lame temporary work-around until I work out how to
  // properly randomize the array from $this->GetAllQuotes(string)
  $quotes = $this->GetAllQuotes($author);
  $rand_item = shuffle($quotes);
  $rand_arr[] = $quotes[$rand_item];
  return $rand_arr;
}

/**
* @protected
* Retrieves a collection of Quote objects from the datasource
* @param string $author An optional author to filter on
* @return array 
*/
protected function GetAllQuotes($author='') {
  // This code builds Quotes array from XML datasource
}
```

I'd really like the GetRandom function to return a randomized array of Quote objects rather than just a single one but the shuffle() feature doesn't seem to work as advertised, at least not if the array is populated with custom objects.

Comment: `shuffle()` returns a bool for success / failure. It randomises the actual array you've passed in.

Comment: `shuffle()` passes value by reference, no need to assign it to variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shuffle takes an array by reference, so you can't use it inline in a return statement. Most array sorting functions in php are by reference.

Solution:

```
public function GetRandom($author='') {
  $quotes = $this->getAllQuotes($author);
  shuffle($quotes); 
  return $quotes;
}
```

Comment: @NealBailey Don't feel foolish. I've asked much much more ignorant questions. My only advice is to "remember the manual" and keep it holy --> http://php.net